# IrfanView stopped recognizing any scanner driver / TWAIN source after either Windows 11 22H2 update or after installation of faulty scanner driver

Tags: drivers, windows-11, scanner, irfanview, windows-11-v22h2

When I select File > Select Scan/TWAIN Source... menu item, I see an empty box with zero items / TWAIN sources / scanner drivers.

[image]

I have three scanner drivers installed in my Windows 11 Pro 22H2. I use two other programs (NAPS2 and Paint) and both of them recognize both sources / drivers without any problems and can scan images from these sources.

[image]

It all started a week or two ago with installation (and then deinstallation) of what turned out to be an incorrect printer driver. Ever since then all drivers are gone (fron IrfanView only).

Restarted computer many times. No effect. I have uninstalled my old 4.35, deleted C:\Program Files\Irfan View folder and installed back the newest 4.60 64-bit. No effect.

**What else can I try to resolve this issue?**

The story in details (if needed) goes like this:

1. I had two scanners (bundled with HP multi-devices: HP LaserJet 1530 and HP LaserJet M426) and IrfanView 4.35.
2. I've been scanning using this software-hardware setup for ages (years). All OK.
3. Tried to install third (old Plustek flatbed scanner), but I used wrong driver (so I wasn't able to scan from it using any software).
4. Uninstalled the faulty driver and trashed the old scanner (no Windows 11 scanner or support available).
5. After 2-3 days I noticed that IrfanView sees no TWAIN sources (where previously it saw two).
6. I have uninstalled IrfanView 4.35 completely and installed 4.60 in its place.
7. No scanner / TWAIN sources again.
8. I have installed drivers for my third scanner.

And the story returned back to point 5th. IrfanView sees neither this new scanner nor two older ones, while Windows 11 Pro and all other image-related software (Paint and NAPS2 in my case) sees all three drivers and is able to scan from all these TWAIN sources without any problems.

[image]

There's also a chance that the above story has nothing to do with this and that IrfanView stopped seeing any TWAIN source after recent update to (the newest) Windows 11 Pro 22H2. As these two events (Windows update and scanner access lost in IrfanView) happened in the fairly the same moment of time.

Has anyone of you already updated Windows 11 to 22H2 and can confirm that TWAIN sources are still there, as there were before this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://irfanview-forum.de/forum/program/support/95958-irfanview-does-not-recognize-any-installed-scanner

I signed up here, because I had the same issue, and I actually managed to fix it. It's actually caused by an incorrect copy of the twain selector .dll (TWAINDSM.dll) that some scanner drivers add in the system folders. Irfranview then ends up loading it instead of the correct twain_32.dll that comes bundled with Windows.

To fix this, open a cmd prompt with admin rights and navigate to system32. Then run the following commands:

**regsvr32 /u TWAINDSM.dll** (this unregisters the dll if it's in use, if you get an error just ignore it, it probably wasn't registered then)

**del /f TWAINDSM.dll**

Repeat the same process for syswow64 folder. The scanner select window should work again.

Comment: I managed to fix this issue some other way (really don't remember, how; one day, out of nowhere all my scanners has returned). But, I am accepting your answer since it can be a valuable source od solutions for others.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that after the update to Windows 11 22H2 the TWAIN drivers have disappeared. Now I can use in IrfanView 4.62 32-bit only with the Canon Lide 400 Driver

[image: Canon Lide 400 Driver]

My Windows 11 is 22H2 (OS Build 22610.1)

I had a suggestion that the drivers were 32-bit, so I installed the 32-bit IrfanView to make sure it works better with them.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, because it partially resolved my issue. Installing 32-bit IrfanView did forced scanners to appear in "Select Source" window. But selecting any of it and then clicking OK in TWAIN Acquire window brings no effect. As an effect, my IrfanView stopped being usable for any kind of scanning.

Comment: I would proceed with the installation of the drivers of the scanner, then. If after selecting the scanner it cannot proceed - re-installing the scanner-drivers should help. One more, but important thing is to install the IrfanView Plugins (32-bit), they contain support for numerous formats, and may help for scanning to work too.   https://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm